# Emulate Python Random Module in .net

Tags: .net

Is there an easy way to emulate Random Module in .net using C#? Preferably a library. I need to run it in .net 4.5.

I need to provide a specific seed and replicate random numbers generated by Python in .net environment.  I need  the randint(x, y) to provide the same sequence of random numbers.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you looked at the Python source code?

Comment: There's also a Python implementation for .NET. Try Nugetting "IronPython".